# Make jQuery native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fix the following jQuery to vanilla-JS.

```
// 1⃣Disables only "a" element links contained in a particular element.
$(function() {
    let target = //document.querySelector('.ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text__1jsQC.ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text--SpaceOut__3kF8R').querySelectorAll('a');
        $('.ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text__1jsQC.ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text--SpaceOut__3kF8R a');
    //document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    target.contents().unwrap();
});


// 2⃣Only link clicks on the "a" element contained in a particular element are disabled.
$(function() {
    var target = $('.ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text--preLine__2SRma a');
    target.click((e) => {
        let link = '/((\bhttps?:\/\/+?[\w=.?&\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w?&\.\/;#~%"=\+-]*>$)|\bftp:\/\/+?[\w=.?&\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w?&\.\/;#~%"=\+-]*>$)|\b\/\/+?[\w=.?&\/-;#~%-]+(\.com\/|\.co\.jp\/|www\.)+(?![\w?&\.\/;#~%"=\+-]*>$)|\bhttps?:\/\/\r?\n.+?[\w=.?&\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w?&\.\/;#~%"=\+-]*>$)))/';
        e.preventDefault();
        var loadContents = $(this).attr('title');
        var k = '#' + loadContents;
        $('#sec').load(link + k);
    });
});
```

I actually tried it, but I can't fix it as I expected.
Regarding 1⃣, it seems that it is not just the problem of how to specify the element.

In case of 2⃣, it works with `$ ('a')`.
If you specify something like `document.querySelectorAll ('a')`, the behavior will be quite different. I will click it without permission.

```
//1⃣Disables only "a" element links contained in a particular element.
//It doesn't work even if I replace it with "$". It seems that it is not just the problem of element specification.
(function (){
let target = //document.querySelector('.ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text__1jsQC.ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text--SpaceOut__3kF8R').querySelectorAll('a');
$('.ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text__1jsQC.ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text--SpaceOut__3kF8R a');
//document.getElementsByTagName('a');
//.contents().unwrap();
target.contentDocument.
Array.prototype.slice.call(target.contentDocument).forEach(function(el){
    Array.prototype.slice.call(el.childNodes).forEach(function(child){
      el.parentNode.insertBefore(child, el);
    });
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  });
})();


//2⃣Only link clicks on the "a" element contained in a particular element are disabled.
//I'm trying pure Javascript. Just change the "$" in the target element.
(function() {
    var target2 = //$('.ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text--preLine__2SRma a');
        document.querySelector('.ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text--preLine__2SRma a');
    //document.querySelector('.ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text--preLine__2SRma').querySelectorAll('a');
    //document.querySelector('.ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text--preLine__2SRma').getElementsByTagName("a");
    //document.querySelectorAll('a');
    //document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    //document.querySelector(".ClapLv1TextBlock_Chie-TextBlock__Text--medium__3nLu4 > a");
    let link = '/((\bhttps?:\/\/+?[\w=.?&\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w?&\.\/;#~%"=\+-]*>$)|\bftp:\/\/+?[\w=.?&\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w?&\.\/;#~%"=\+-]*>$)|\b\/\/+?[\w=.?&\/-;#~%-]+(\.com\/|\.co\.jp\/|www\.)+(?![\w?&\.\/;#~%"=\+-]*>$)|\bhttps?:\/\/\r?\n.+?[\w=.?&\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w?&\.\/;#~%"=\+-]*>$)))/';
        target2.click((e) => {
            //Disable link clicks
            e.preventDefault();
            for (let i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
                if (target2.innerHTML.match(link[i])) {
                    link[i].getAttribute('title');
                    var k = '#' + loadContents;
                    var myXml = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    myXml.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if ((myXml.readyState === 4) && (myXml.status === 200)) {
                            document.querySelector('#sec').innerHTML = myXml.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    myXml.open("GET", link + k, true);
                    myXml.send(null);
                }
            }
        });

})();
```

Anyway, I want to fix even just 1⃣.

please tell me.

Comment: You've got some seriously long class selectors there... Why not simplify those by making them smaller?

Comment: What does I will click it without permission mean?

Comment: `@ jqueryHtmlCSS5`

It was translated, so it may not have been transmitted.

I want to disable the click, but when I specify the element in native JS, the click is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disables only "a" element links contained in a particular element.

   - The first thing to replace is the $(function() {...}); which you already did with (function() {...})();
   - The next thing you want to do, is replace the $('.test a'). The equivalent for this is [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for the first result or [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for an array of all the matched results.
   - To loop through the resultant array, we use [array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
   - The next thing to replace is the .unwrap function. This basically takes an element's [outertHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) and replaces is with the element's [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

```js
(() => {
  let target = document.querySelectorAll('.test a');
  target.forEach(t => t.outerHTML = t.innerHTML);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>JQuery to JavaScript</title>
  <head>
  
  <body>
    <p class="test">
      This is a <a href="/">test</a>.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. Only link clicks on the "a" element contained in a particular element are disabled.

   - Not sure exactly what the regular expression is supposed to do - running the code seems to generate errors, but I gave my best guess in the answer.
   - We've already gone over some of the concepts in the first answer, so skipping those.
   - we replace target.click by adding an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the selected element. An improvement might be `document.querySelectorAll('.test a[href]')` to only get anchor tags with an href element.
   - We then do an Ajax call and write the result of the call to element with the id `sec`.
   - We use the [match function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to check the url against the regular expression. If it matches, we do the Ajax query, if not, we do nothing.

```js
(() => {
  let target = document.querySelectorAll('.test a');
  target.forEach(href => {
    href.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let link = /((\bhttps?:\/\/+?[\w=.?&\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w?&\.\/;#~%"=\+-]*>$)|\bftp:\/\/+?[\w=.?&\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w?&\.\/;#~%"=\+-]*>$)|\b\/\/+?[\w=.?&\/-;#~%-]+(\.com\/|\.co\.jp\/|www\.)+(?![\w?&\.\/;#~%"=\+-]*>$)|\bhttps?:\/\/\r?\n.+?[\w=.?&\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w?&\.\/;#~%"=\+-]*>$)))/;
      
      let matched = false;
      e.target.getAttribute('href') && (matched = e.target.getAttribute('href').match(link));
      if (!matched) {
        //No match - do nothing
        return;
      }
      matched = matched[0];
      
      let loadContents = e.target.getAttribute('title');
      let k = '#' + loadContents;

      //Do Ajax call
      let xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (
          xmlHttpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE &&
          xmlHttpRequest.status >= 200 && xmlHttpRequest.status < 300 //Remove if you want error responses
        ) {
          document.querySelector('#sec').innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
        }
      };
      xmlHttpRequest.open('GET', matched + k);
      xmlHttpRequest.send();
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>JQuery to JavaScript</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <p class="test">
      This is a <a href="https://www.test.com/" title="test">test</a>.
    </p>
    
    <div id="sec"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is at least a partial solution to your first question:

```js
// 1. Disables only "a" element links contained in a particular element.

// jQuery:
// $(function() { $('.class1.class2 a').contents().unwrap(); });
// Vanilla JS:
document.querySelectorAll('.class1.class2 a').forEach(a=>a.parentNode.innerHTML=a.innerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class2 class1"><span><a href="abc.html">link to abc</a></span></div>
<div class="class3 class1"><span><a href="def.html">link to def</a></span></div>
```

As Dale Landra already sugguested, I shortened your class names here to improve the readability of the example.